# LINQ query to group data between two list collections, populating a nested object (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, linq, list, collections, aggregate

I have these objects:

```
Public Class MakeInfo
  Public Property Name As String
  Public Property Description As String
  Public Property Stock As StockInfo
End Class

Public Class ModelInfo
  Public Property Make As String
  Public Property Name As String
  Public Property Description As String
  Public Property Stock As StockInfo
End Class

Public Class StockInfo
  Public Property Count As Integer
  Public Property MinPrice As Double
End Class
```

Using LINQ I need to take a List(Of MakeInfo) and a List(Of ModelInfo) and aggregate the StockInfo from ModelInfo into the List(Of MakeInfo).

So for each MakeInfo I will have a total count of all stock where MakeInfo.Name = ModelInfo.Make, and also a minimum price.

I think it's going to be something like this, but I'm having trouble accessing the nested object and not sure if it's going to be possible with a single query. I've tried a few variations, but here's where I'm up to:

```
newList = From ma In makeData _
          Group Join mo In modelData _
          On ma.Name Equals mo.Make _
          Into Group _
          Select New MakeInfo With {.Name = m.Name, _
                                    .Description = m.Description, _
                                    .Stock = ?}
```

Comment: Please show us what you've got thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the right way to do this and it doesn't require loop iteration:

```
Dim new_makes = From ma In makes
                Join mo In models On mo.Make Equals ma.Name
                Group By ma.Name, ma.Description
                Into TotalCount = Sum(mo.Stock.Count), LowestPrice = Min(mo.Stock.MinPrice)
                Select New MakeInfo With {.Name = Name, _
                                          .Description = Description, _
                                          .Stock = New StockInfo With {.Count = TotalCount, .MinPrice = LowestPrice}}
```

I was certain that it would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are actually trying to modify the original `MakeInfo` objects, you should stop the query with the group.  `newList` will have each make paired with the group of models of that make.  You can iterate through newList, and for each make, aggregate the models into the `StockInfo` for the make.

```
Dim newList = From ma In makeData _
              Group Join mo In modelData _
              On ma.Name Equals mo.Make _
              Into Group
For Each g In newList
    g.ma.Stock = g.Group.Aggregate(
                    New StockInfo() With {.MinPrice = Double.NaN},
                    Function(si, model)
                        Return New StockInfo With {
                                     .Count = si.Count + 1,
                                     .MinPrice = If(Double.IsNaN(si.MinPrice) OrElse
                                                    model.Stock.MinPrice < si.MinPrice,
                                                    model.Stock.MinPrice,
                                                    si.MinPrice)}
                    End Function)
Next
```

If you actually want new instances, just change the loop to create a new item instead of modifying the existing make.

```
Dim results As New List(Of MakeInfo)()
For Each g In newList
    Dim newMake As New MakeInfo()
    newMake.Name = g.ma.Name
    newMake.Description = g.ma.Description
    newMake.Stock = g.Group.Aggregate( same as before )
    results.Add(newMake)
Next
```

Comment: I thought there might be a way to do it without using a loop, perhaps I was being ridiculous (?). I've found LINQ to not perform much quicker than just doing the whole thing with a couple of loops and building the results up to a new collection. Having said that, I've used the second portion of code and got it working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I found a better solution - I have added a new answer.